# Create objects of derived classes in base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

This is my code down here. I am trying to create objects from derived classes in the base class, but it has some errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

class PrgDevice {
private:
    tm startTime;
    tm stopTime;
    int choice;
    int choice1;
    char c;
public:
    int dateTime() {
        cout << "Enter start date and start time: ";
        cin >> startTime.tm_mday >> startTime.tm_mon >> startTime.tm_year >> startTime.tm_hour >> startTime.tm_min >> startTime.tm_sec;
        cout << "Enter stop date and stop time: ";
        cin >> stopTime.tm_mday >> stopTime.tm_mon >> stopTime.tm_year >> stopTime.tm_hour >> stopTime.tm_min >> stopTime.tm_sec;
    }

    void mainMenu() {
        while (choice != 3) {
            cout << "Main menu options:";
            cout << "      1. Select a device to program (contains a submenu)" << endl;
            cout << "      2. Display current status of all devices" << endl;
            cout << "      3. Exit" << endl;
            cout << "Enter your option => ";
            cin >> choice;

            if (choice == 1) {
                subMenu();
            }
            else if (choice == 2) {
                cout << choice;
            }
            else {

            }
        }
        system("pause");
    }
    void subMenu() {
        cout << "Select a device:" << endl;
        cout << "         1. PVR" << endl;
        cout << "         2. Camera DVR" << endl;
        cout << "         3. Oven" << endl;
        cout << "Enter your option => ";
        cin >> choice1;

        if (choice1 == 1) {
            PVR n1;
        }
        else if (choice1 == 2) {
            DVR n2;
        }
        else {
            Oven n3;
        }
    }
    void newDevice() {
        if (c == 'Y' || c == 'y') {
            subMenu();
        }
        else {
            mainMenu();
        }
    }
};

class PVR : public PrgDevice {
private:
    int channel;
public:
    PVR() {
        cout << "Select the channel ==> ";
        cin >> channel;
        cout << endl;
        dateTime();
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Another device to program Y/N ? => ";
        newDevice();
    }
};

class DVR : public PrgDevice {
private:
    string position;
public:
    DVR() {
        cout << "Select the position ==> ";
        getline(cin, position);
        cout << endl;
        dateTime();
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Another device to program Y/N ? => ";
        newDevice();
    }
};

class Oven : public PrgDevice {
private:
    string food;
public:
    Oven() {
        cout << "What do you want to bake? ==> ";
        getline(cin, food);
        cout << endl;
        dateTime();
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Another device to program Y/N ? => ";
        newDevice();
    }
};

int main() {
    PrgDevice obj1;
    obj1.mainMenu();



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the errors:

> error C2065: 'PVR': undeclared identifier
>   error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'n1'
>    error C2065: 'n1': undeclared identifier
>   error C2065: 'DVR': undeclared identifier
>   error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'n2'
>    error C2065: 'n2': undeclared identifier
>   error C2065: 'Oven': undeclared identifier
>   error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'n3'
>    error C2065: 'n3': undeclared identifier
>   1>Done building project "Project1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: You cannot use the classes there since they haven't been defined when you use them. You should split the definition of those functions from the declaration and define them below the classes you want to use.

Comment: a class should be responsible for one thing. All your classes are doing too much. You are mixing user input and logic. A base should typically not know about its derived classes. Fixing your code would require lots of refactoring, hope you are lucky and someone passes by who can see the bigger picture here

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear why you are using inheritance here. Essentialy the three objects `PVR` `DVR` and `Oven` do not need to derive from `PrgDevice`. Once they don't derive you can move them before `PrgDevice` so that you can use them there.

```
class PVR {...
};
class DVR  {...
};
class Oven {...
};
class PrgDevice {...
};
```

Since the `PVR` `DVR` and `Oven` constructors all do

```
dateTime();
cout << endl;
cout << "Another device to program Y/N ? => ";
newDevice();
```

we can move that into the `PrgDevice::submenu` function.

```
void subMenu() { ...
  if (choice1 == 1) {
     PVR n1;
  }
  else if (choice1 == 2) {
     DVR n2;
  }
  else {
    Oven n3;
  }
  dateTime();
  cout << endl;
  cout << "Another device to program Y/N ? => ";
  newDevice();
}
```

That however does not solve all your problems. You keep recursing:

- `mainMenu` calls `subMenu`
- `submenu` calls `newDevice`
- `newDevice` calls `submenu` or `newDevice`

which will need fixing next. New device should really either stay in `submenu` or **return** to the main menu. We do that by adding a `do` `while` loop

```
void submenu()
{
  do {
      cout << "Select a device:" << endl;
      ...
      cout << "Another device to program Y/N ? => ";

      cin >> c;
  }
  while(c == 'Y' || c == 'y');
}
```

I've left a seemingly working version with a commented out `datetime` function [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/597018f92277305e)

Fed with

```
echo -e "1 1 1 y 2 2\n n 3"
```

It outputs

```
Main menu options: 
      1. Select a device to program (contains a submenu)
      2. Display current status of all devices
      3. Exit
Enter your option => Select a device:
         1. PVR
         2. Camera DVR
         3. Oven
Enter your option => Select the channel ==> 

Another device to program Y/N ? => Select a device:
         1. PVR
         2. Camera DVR
         3. Oven
Enter your option => Select the position ==> 

Another device to program Y/N ? => Main menu options: 
      1. Select a device to program (contains a submenu)
      2. Display current status of all devices
      3. Exit
Enter your option =>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your object types before using them. Instead of inlining your code in your class definition, separate them out at the top of your code (or in includes), and then when you actually start using them, the compiler has a clue what you're doing.

```
class A {
    // Define stuff, but don't inline your methods
}

class B: public A {
    // Define stuff, but don't inline your methods
};

void A::subMenu() {
    // All your code
}
```